# Electron ipcRenderer events in a React class component

Tags: reactjs, events, event-handling, electron

I am using Electron with React and I am facing a little problem.

I trigger an event (ipcRenderer.send) in component's willMount method and listen for the response (ipcRenderer.on) in component't didMount method.

But I get a warning in the console (see below) when i try to setState in the listener.

**warning.js:35 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component**.

Here is the code:

```
    import {remote, ipcRenderer} from 'electron';
    import React from 'react';
    import ListItem from './ListItem';

    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
      packages: []
     }
     this.updatePackages = this.updatePackages.bind(this);
    }

    updatePackages(packages) {
      this.setState({
        packages: packages
      });
    }

    componentWillMount() {
     ipcRenderer.send('get-global-packages');
    }

    componentDidMount() {
     ipcRenderer.on('get-global-packages-reply', (event, packages) => 
     {
      this.updatePackages(packages);
     });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
     ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners(['get-global-packages-reply');
    }

    render() {
     let packages = this.props.packages;
     if(!packages) {
      return null;
     }
     return (
      <div className="packages-list" ref={(el) => {
        this.list = el;
       }}/>
       {packages.map((pkg, idx) => {
         return <ListItem key={idx} {...pkg}/>
       })}
      </div>
     )
    }
```

I have read the related post [ipcRenderer in React component constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41156945/ipcrenderer-in-react-component-constructor)

where he uses ref which i did, but now the root variable is null,
this means to me that the component is not mounted.

```
updatePackages(packages) {
 let root = this.list;
 if(root) {
  this.setState({
   packages: packages
  });
 }
}
```

What can I do to clear the warning or use the ref prop correctly?

related project repo):
https://github.com/rvpanoz/luna

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend sending the message to the main process also in componentDidMount. By sending it in componentWillMount, you may be giving rise to a race condition..

Comment: hello sashi, thanks for your answer. I tried what you suggest with the sams results.